# Index out of bounds of array error when parsing font string?

Tags: c#, winforms, string, fonts, parsing

i keep getting an "Index is out of bounds of array" error on line # 574 which is:

label.Font = new Font(fontNameFields[0], Single.Parse(fontNameFields[1]));

... The following text file i am parsing contains this exact information:

```
Label
"hi tyler"
23, 76
Arial,12.5
```

...I can successfully parse all the other info (just not the very last line), and the code i have is:

```
MatchCollection lines = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(Path), @"(.+?)\r\n""([^""]+)""\r\n(\d+), (\d+)");
foreach (Match match in lines)
{
    string control = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string text = match.Groups[2].Value;
    int x = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
    int y = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value);
    String cfont = match.Groups[5].Value;
    string color = match.Groups[6].Value;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, \"{1}\", {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", control, text, x, y, cfont, color);



    switch (control)
    {
        case "Label":
            Label label = new Label();    

            label.Text = text;

            label.AutoSize = true;
            label.IsAccessible = true;

            label.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(label_MouseClick);
            label.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(label_MouseDoubleClick);
            label.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(label_MouseDown);
            label.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(label_MouseMove);
            label.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(label_MouseUp);

            label.Location = new Point(x, y);
            canvas.Controls.Add(label);

                            String fontName = cfont;
    String[] fontNameFields = fontName.Split(',');


    label.Font = new Font(fontNameFields[0], Single.Parse(fontNameFields[1]));
```

...i think there may be something wrong with the regex that gets the font stuff... i dont know, but it just won't work, can somebody please help?

For a history of this problem, see: [Parsing font info and converting it to System.Drawing.Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519477/parsing-font-info-and-converting-it-to-system-drawing-font/1519491#1519491)

Comment: What does your `Console.WriteLine` statement output?

Comment: i dont know. its a winforms app, so no console window appears. i simply forgot to remove that line

Comment: You're asking for help, but can't be bothered to do your own debugging? Ever heard of `MessageBox.Show`?

Comment: i've been debugging for over 3hours. and if you've read the history in the link provided in this question, you'd see that.

Also, like i explained in the comments in my other question, MessageBox.Show() displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@"(.+?)\r\n""([^""]+)""\r\n(\d+), (\d+)\r\n(\w+,\d+\.?\d)"
```

It is similar to slashmais solution, only a bit more restrictive in terms of what is a font and its size, and closer to your original, which I like because the blocks are more explicitly visible.

Comment: thank you mjv - there r no errors on your regex which i reallt like, however, i am still getting than silly out of bounds error on line:

label.Font = new Font(fontNameFields[0], Single.Parse(fontNameFields[1]));

Comment: @baeltazor  I failed to see that your logic expected this font line as one single token, later to be split, before the Font = new Font() line in the program.   Check in a minute, I'll edit the regex accordingly!